# Play2.11 Play can not find the model class but I can run pure JPA Junit test properly

Tags: jpa, model, playframework-2.0

I am using Play2.11 Java and JPA2.0 Hibernate implementation and mysql

I can run the Junit test case properly to run CURD operation on the models which put a persistence.xml under test/meat-inf, but when run play to CURD from the web page, it shows can not find the models.*** class. After some time digging still do not have a clue. please help to check, thanks a lot
The exception is:

```
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: DEVUnit] class or package not found
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1416) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addClassesToSessionFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:1199) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1063) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:293) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:374) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:71) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar:1.0.1.Final]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar:1.0.1.Final]
    at prefix.platform.Global.<clinit>(Global.java:8) ~[na:na]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: models.Account
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$53$$anonfun$55$$anon$2.loadClass(PlayCommands.scala:535) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.classForName(Ejb3Configuration.java:1333) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1405) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

**conf/meta-inf/persistence.xml**:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="DEVUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>dev</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>models.Account</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**test/meta-inf/persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="DEVUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>models.Account</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="***" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="***" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://****.net:3306/dev?characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Only one line different the `<non-jta-data-source>dev</non-jta-data-source>`

**conf/application.conf**

```
# This is the main configuration file for the application.
# ~~~~~

# Secret key
# ~~~~~
# The secret key is used to secure cryptographics functions.
# If you deploy your application to several instances be sure to use the same key!
application.secret="Qk5y/1b1;]>p=yo6?/FnmQR4F@W2lGYWfJI>e4oBs2D0nahNl>Y40y1A:P[uc;RJ"

# The application languages
# ~~~~~
application.langs="en"

# Global object class
# ~~~~~
# Define the Global object class for this application.
# Default to Global in the root package.
#application.global=Global
#ehcacheplugin=disabled
# Router 
# ~~~~~
# Define the Router object to use for this application.
# This router will be looked up first when the application is starting up,
# so make sure this is the entry point. 
# Furthermore, it's assumed your route file is named properly. 
# So for an application router like `conf/my.application.Router`,
# you may need to define a router file `my.application.routes`.
# Default to Routes in the root package (and `conf/routes`)
# application.router=my.application.Routes

# Database configuration
# ~~~~~ 
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://****.net/dev?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.user=***
db.default.password=****
db.default.jndiName=dev
#
# You can expose this datasource via JNDI if needed (Useful for JPA)
# db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS




# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed
evolutionplugin=disabled

# Logger
# ~~~~~
# You can also configure logback (http://logback.qos.ch/), by providing a logger.xml file in the conf directory .

# Root logger:
logger.root=ERROR

# Logger used by the framework:
logger.play=INFO

# Logger provided to your application:
logger.application=DEBUG
```

Comment: I Found the reason but no solution yet, please look at my another post thanks  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545907/play2-can-create-entitymanagerfactory-manually-then-create-entitymanager-like-fa

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, it seems:  my JPA code (written in Scala, not Java) ran fine outside of Play (the Scala version), but inside it just wouldn't work.  I tinkered with a lot of persistence.xml changes, tried a lot of examples, no dice.  JPA just couldn't find my entity classes.

Eventually I got it to work with the following:

1. add `sbt.PlayKeys.javaJpa` to "appDependencies" in `Build.scala` (not sure why I had to qualify it and not specify just "javaJpa", but I do)
2. use `play.db.jpa.JPA.em()` to create the entity manager; for whatever reason you can't create it yourself
3. add `jpa.name = name` to `application.conf` where "name" is the name of my persistence-unit

Step 3 took awhile to figure out, and that was by digging through the source of JPA and JPAPlugin.  If you leave it out, the JPA class will complain `"No JPA EntityManagerFactory configured for name [whatever]"` even though "whatever" is well defined in your `persistence.xml` file.  *WHY* we need another level of indirection in naming things I don't know, but... that finally made it work.

Comment: Thanks Rodney, I open another thread to talk about this question, I wrote a a util class to work around this. And recently I found the the root cause is the JPA classloader logic, so only will work via Play plugin.
The util class is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545907/play2-can-create-entitymanagerfactory-manually-then-create-entitymanager-like-fa