# Play2 How to manage the transaction from the service layer instead of action layer?

Tags: jpa, playframework-2.0

I am using Play2.1.1 Java with JPA2.0 with hibernate implementation.

to control the transaction by code instead of using @transactional like below is the normal JPA code style, Is there any way to work like below at Play? or how to use JPA.withtranaction() to do? I tried it, no idea how to pass in the parameter, I am not familiar with functional code. thanks a lot. Please give me some sample code based on below.

```
public  void createActorB(final String email, final String psw) throws Throwable {
    EntityManager manager = JPA.em();
    try {
        EntityTransaction ex = manager.getTransaction();
        this.dbActor.setEmail(email);
        this.dbActor.setCredential(psw);
        manager.persist(this.dbActor);
        ex.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ActorException(CODE.UNKNOWN, e);
    } finally {
        manager.close();
    }
}
```

Now I change my code below to start transaction from service layer, It does not looks efficient, is there any other way to write? thanks

```
private void internalCreateActor(String email, String psw) throws ActorException {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(email) || StringUtils.isEmpty(psw))
            throw new ActorException(CODE.INVALIDE_PARAMETER);
        try {
            this.dbActor.setEmail(email);
            this.dbActor.setCredential(psw);
            this.dbActor.setCreateD(new Date());
            JPA.em().persist(this.dbActor);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ActorException(CODE.UNKNOWN, e);
        }
    }

 public void createActor(final String email, final String psw, final String cellPhone, final Actor.TYPE type)
            throws Throwable {

        JPA.withTransaction(new Callback0() {
            @Override
            public void invoke() throws Throwable {
                internalCreateActor(email, psw, cellPhone, type);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @biesior  I updated the version and write current walk around, is there any other solution? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time research, I write a method JPAUtil referring to JPA provided by Play which can use normally to control the transaction manually from the service layer actually everywhere.

```
public class JPAUtil {

    static ThreadLocal<EntityManager> currentEntityManager = new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>();

    /**
     * Get the EntityManager for specified persistence unit for this thread.
     */
    public static EntityManager em(String key) {
        Application app = Play.application();
        if (app == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No application running");
        }

        JPAPlugin jpaPlugin = app.plugin(JPAPlugin.class);
        if (jpaPlugin == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No JPA EntityManagerFactory configured for name [" + key + "]");
        }

        EntityManager em = jpaPlugin.em(key);
        if (em == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No JPA EntityManagerFactory configured for name [" + key + "]");
        }

        bindForCurrentThread(em);

        return em;
    }

    /**
     * Get the default EntityManager for this thread.
     */
    public static EntityManager em() {
        EntityManager em = currentEntityManager.get();
        if (em == null) {
            return em(Constants.DATASOURCEKEY);
        }
        return em;
    }

    /**
     * Bind an EntityManager to the current thread.
     */
    public static void bindForCurrentThread(EntityManager em) {
        currentEntityManager.set(em);
    }

    public static void closeEM() {
        EntityManager em = currentEntityManager.get();
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
        bindForCurrentThread(null);
    }

    public static void beginTransaction() {
        em().getTransaction().begin();
    }

    public static void commitTransaction() {
        em().getTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: That looks a lot like https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-java-jpa/src/main/java/play/db/jpa/JPA.java

Comment: It is, I copy the idea from the JPA. Using JPAUtil you can manage the transaction life cycle as normal JPA2.0 way instead of managing by Play framework.

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
public static User getUserByIdentity(final AuthUserIdentity identity) {
    try {
        return JPA.withTransaction(new play.libs.F.Function0<User>() {
            public User apply() {       
                return User.findByAuthUserIdentity(identity);
            }
        });
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new RuntimeException(t);
    }       
}
```