# How to pass http header as hibernate filter in dropwizard?

Tags: hibernate, http-headers, jersey, dropwizard, hibernate-filters

I'm working on a multitenant application, using Hibernate's @Filter annotation to filter entities by user implicitly (as described in this blog: http://blog.lunatech.com/2011/03/04/play-framework-writing-multitenancy-application-hibernate-filters)

Tenant id is passed in HTTP header, which is intercepted by Jersey filter and set in Hibernate session using below code:

```
public class TenantFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public TenantFilter(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
        String tenantId = request.getHeaderValue("X-TENANT-ID");
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
        currentSession.enableFilter("tenant").setParameter("tenant_id", tenantId);
        return request;
    }
}
```

But, this filter parameter is not set when DAO executes query, because hibernate session used in Resource method and Filter are not the same (Using currentSession results in a session not available error)

How can i pass tenant parameter to Hibernate session in Dropwizard in the same transaction context as Dropwizard Resource method? Jersey filter does not execute in the same transaction context, since @UnitOfWork is on Resource method.

Comment: Hey there, Im trying to do exactly the same things as you -- implement Dropwizard with a multi-tenant data architecture. Did you ever manage to find a solution to your problem?

Comment: I ended up implementing a library for adding multitenancy to hibernate DAOs in dropwizard: https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/dropwizard-multitenancy

Answer (score 0):

In play the db sessions are handled by the framework itself.
Like opening connection and set that opened session for the current thread / whoever annotated with @Transaction will be available there only.
You can't open the session and close the session in your code.

you have to create your own JPAPlugin like play's jpa plugin.
Create one session for every request and associate that with current thread (Threadlocal) and use it until the request has been processed.

During the initial creation of session you can enable the filter and at the end of the request process you can disable the filter and close the session.

In this is way we handled the roles and permissions in our applications (using Aspects).

Please have a look at the below post it will give some idea on how to create your own db plugin.

[Play2 How to manage the transaction from the service layer instead of action layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545907/play2-how-to-manage-the-transaction-from-the-service-layer-instead-of-action-lay)

Hope this will give some hint.

SessionImplementor currentSession = ((SessionImplementor)em(key).getDelegate());
currentSession.enableFilter("tenant").setParameter("tenant_id", tenantId);